# Request JSON to load into Javascript object. Differences in response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Take a look at this function first, notice the json file is located locally:

```
if (request) {
    request.open("GET", "flicks.json", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            var testi = request.responseText;
            var listmovies = JSON.parse(testi);
            console.log(typeof testi); // THIS RETURNS STRING
            console.log(typeof listmovies); // THIS RETURNS OBJECT - YAY!
          }
    };
    request.send(null);
}
```

That's perfect, I got what I wanted, an object with the JSON data in it.

But when I changed the location of the JSON file and I put it on a server:

```
request.open("GET", "http://www.myserver.com/flicks.json", true);
```

Then it comes back with this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

Example JSON

```
{
    "feed": "....",
    "description": "Fake List of Netflix movies",
    "modified": "2010-10-25T15:04:46Z",
    "generator": "I did it",
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "...",
            "link": "h...",
            "media": {
                "m": "..."
            },
            "date_taken": "..."
        },
        {
            "title": "...",
            "link": "...",
            "media": {
                "m": "..."
            },
            "date_taken": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does it work locally but not the other way?

Comment: Do you have any other messages? What does the net tab of your browser's developer tools say about the request? Why are you checking the readyState but not the status?

Comment: If I add the request.status == 200 then it doesn't return anything when I do console.log(etc..) It just says 200 OK on the console, nothing else.

Comment: {
    "feed": "....",
    "description": "Fake List of Netflix movies",
    "modified": "2010-10-25T15:04:46Z",
    "generator": "I did it",
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "...",
            "link": "h...",
            "media": {
                "m": "..."
            },
            "date_taken": "..."
        },
        {
            "title": "...",
            "link": "...",
            "media": {
                "m": "..."
            },
            "date_taken": "..."
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

If you put: `http://www.myserver.com/flicks.json` in a browser, can you see the data? (Is the file reachable).  Second guess, are you sure the files are identical(local vs server)?

EDIT 1:
Try this.  just a slight change in order of calls.

```
if (request) {
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            var testi = request.responseText;
            var listmovies = JSON.parse(testi);
            console.log(typeof testi); // THIS RETURNS STRING
            console.log(typeof listmovies); // THIS RETURNS OBJECT - YAY!
          }
    };
    request.open("GET", "http://www.myserver.com/flicks.json", true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, it is absolutely identical and I can see the data. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm stumped.

Comment: Actually, let's try changing the order of the calls. Move: request.open to be after: request.onreadystatechange (I have trouble giving up on things. :p)

Comment: I'll try that, also I just tried it on Chrome and it comes back with this error: “Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin”

Comment: have you tried without `null` in `.send()`?  The [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) example does not have it there.

Comment: You cannot call a JSON service from harddisk in Chrome. You need a proxy or load the page that does the request from a server

Comment: @Grallen: I'm afraid the order of calls hasn't changed anything.

Comment: @Grallen I mean it works if the json is local but not when using the absolute path...